# If two algebras are generated by the same elements, then are they isomorphic?

Tags: algebras, hecke-algebras

The $0$-Hecke algebra $\mathcal{H}_0(S_{n+1})$ is generated by $\{ h_1, \ldots,h_n\}$ satisfying

i) $h_i^2=-h_i$

ii) $h_ih_j=h_jh_i$ if $|j-i| > 1$

iii) $h_ih_{i+1}h_i=h_{i+1}h_ih_{i+1}$.

Now, suppose $R$ is an algebra with basis $\{e_w : w \in S_{n+1}\}$ and let $\mathcal{R}$ be the subalgebra of $\operatorname{Hom}(R,R)$ generated by $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n:R \to R$ given by

$$\theta_{i}(e_w) = 
\left \{ 
\begin{matrix}
e_{s_iw} & \text{if } \ell(s_iw) > \ell(w), \\
 \\
-e_w & \text{if } \ell(s_iw) < \ell(w).
\end{matrix}
\right. $$

If we show that the $\theta_i$'s also satisfy i), ii) and iii), then does it follow that $\mathcal{R} \cong \mathcal{H}$? The reason I ask is because after showing all of this, Mathas in his book *Iwahori-Hecke Algebras and Schur Algebras of the Symmetric Group*, says that there's only a subjective hom $\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{R}$. So why aren't they isomorphic?

Comment: There may be extra relations that are independent of (i)-(iii).

Comment: In this case, i)-iii) are the defining relations of $\mathcal{H}$ though

Comment: Yes, and if the generators of $\mathcal{R}$ satisfy further relations which are independent of (i)-(iii), then at most you can conclude that $\mathcal{H}$ surjects onto $\mathcal{R}$ (I assume $\mathcal{S}$ is a typo).